# Problem on NVIC STM32F100

Tags: stm32, arm, interrupts

I am using STM32VL discovery board(STM32f100rb6)..
I wrote following code for NVIC:

```
void Interrupt_Init(void)
{
    __enable_irq();
    /*Core Base(NVIC)*/

    //set priority to 0
    //NVIC->IP[6] &= ~((uint32_t)0xff00);

    //Activate Interrupts
    NVIC->ISER[0] |= BIT6;

    //Enable Pending BIT for Interrupt 6
    NVIC->ISPR[0] |= BIT6;
    lcd_writechar('1');
}
```

and

```
int main(void)
{
Interrupt_Init();
    while (1)
    {

    }
}
void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)
{
    //NVIC->ICPR[0] |= BIT6;

    lcd_writechar('2');
}
```

as you see under `Interrupt_Init()` I user `NVIC->ISPR[0] |= BIT6;` phrase to soft-enable exti0-IRQ. so `void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)` subroutine must executed and I got '2' on LCD. but  as `NVIC->ISPR[0] |= BIT6;` execute next line(`lcd_writechar('1');`) never runs.. but when I commented (`NVIC->ISPR[0] |= BIT6;`) I got '1' on LCD... whats going on??

> Update:
>
> I look further into "startup_stm32f10x_md_vl.s" file in my project as
>   startup file:
>
> ```
> .section  .text.Default_Handler,"ax",%progbits
> Default_Handler:
> Infinite_Loop:
>   b  Infinite_Loop
>   .size  Default_Handler, .-Default_Handler
> ```
>
> and:
>
> ```
> g_pfnVectors:
>   .word  _estack
>   .word  Reset_Handler
>   .word  NMI_Handler
>   .word  HardFault_Handler
>   .word  MemManage_Handler
>   .word  BusFault_Handler
>   .word  UsageFault_Handler
>   .word  0
>   .word  0
>   .word  0
>   .word  0
>   .word  SVC_Handler
>   .word  DebugMon_Handler
>   .word  0
>   .word  PendSV_Handler
>   .word  SysTick_Handler
>   .word  WWDG_IRQHandler
>   .word  PVD_IRQHandler
>   .word  TAMPER_IRQHandler
>   .word  RTC_IRQHandler
>   .word  FLASH_IRQHandler
>   .word  RCC_IRQHandler
>   .word  EXTI0_IRQHandler
> ...
> ```
>
> and:
>
> ```
> .weak  EXTI0_IRQHandler
> .thumb_set EXTI0_IRQHandler,Default_Handler
> ```
>
> It seems that "EXTI0_IRQHandler" always equal to "Default_Handler" in
>   my projects so it cause infinite loop as we define above.
>
> I think this part:
>
> ```
> void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)
> {
>   NVIC->ICPR[0] |= BIT6;
>
>   lcd_writechar('2');
> }
> ```
>
> never influences the "EXTI0_IRQHandler" definition. why?

Update:

> Is there any way to jump to
>   EXTI0_IRQHandler without implementing anything in peripheral?? Like asm("B
>   0x58")?  my purpose is to be sure from core configurations then work
>   on peripheral configurations ?

Update:

> I nearly found problem but needs help to fix it.. after many
>   examination and using debug features I found this piece of code is
>   faulty:
>
> ```
>     void EXTI0_IRQHandler()
>     {
>       lcd_writechar('2');
>       LED_ON();
>       NVIC->ICPR[0] |= BIT6;
>     }
> ```
>
> in detail `lcd_writechar('2');` cause to issue because inside function
>   I am using delay() function.This is that piece of code
>   involving delay by SycTick feature:
>
> ```
> /*Enable SysTick*/
>   //Processor clock (AHB)
>   SysTick->CTRL |= BIT2;
>   //Counting down to zero to asserts the SysTick exception request.
>   SysTick->CTRL |= BIT1;
>   SysTick->LOAD = 8000 - 1;
> void SysTick_Handler(void)
> {
>   SysTick_Tick++;
>   //lcd_writechar('7');
>   SCB->ICSR |= BIT25;
> }
> void delay(int ms)
> {
>   SysTick_Tick = 0;
>   //Enable Systick Counter
>   SysTick->CTRL |= BIT0;
>   while (SysTick_Tick < ms) {}
>   //Disable Systick Counter
>   SysTick->CTRL &= ~BIT0;
>   SCB->ICSR |= BIT25;
>   return;
> }
> ```
>
> as you see I am trying to clear pending bit of SysTick by `SCB->ICSR
>   |= BIT25;` but clearly after running of delay() function
>   from inside of `EXTI0_IRQHandler()` everything hangs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the mistake. Priority is the problem.

Use `NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI0_IRQn, 1);` to set SysTick to a higher priority level than EXTI0_IRQn. Then everything goes OK.

Answer (score 4):

When you enter the interrupt routine, you need to clear the interrupt source flag. If you do not clear the flag, when you exit the interrupt routine it will just re-enter the routine. This way you will always be stuck in EXTI0_IRQHandler.

Comment: thank for your answer but how?? may you explain more by example related o this project??

Comment: I use `void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)
{
    NVIC->ICPR[0] |= BIT6;

    lcd_writechar('2');
}` for clearing the interrupt source flag but `lcd_writechar('2')` never runs and everything is the same.

Comment: I am thinking it will always stuck in SysTick_Handler(), please read last update.

Answer (score 3):

The `NVIC->ICPR` only removes the pending bit in the NVIC.
But, if the IRQ signal to the NVIC is still active (the EXTI PR register), the pending bit clear in the NVIC will have no effect.

Instead, you have to clear the interrupt request source, `EXTI->PR = EXTI_PR_PR6` in the ISR. Otherwise you will be tail-chaining this interrupt routine until a higher priority one arrives.

The definitions you find in startup.s are **[weak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol)**, you override these when you write the actual function.

Using `NVIC->ISPR[0] |= BIT6` you generate a software interrupt request. It is cleared when entering the ISR.

General tip, when debugging missing interrupt routines, set a breakpoint here:

```
.section  .text.Default_Handler,"ax",%progbits
Default_Handler:
 Infinite_Loop:
  b  Infinite_Loop  <-------- breakpoint
  .size  Default_Handler, .-Default_Handler
```

Comment: @peymankhalili there are two ways to run the isr by software. Call the function. Or set the pending bit.

Comment: Yes, I did it( set pending bit) by `NVIC->ISPR[0] |= BIT6`, so `void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)` function supposed to run.. but not happening...because we did not get '1' on LCD as `lcd_writechar('1');` admit it.

Comment: @peymankhalili Are you by any change triggering the RCC_IRQHandler?

Comment: no, I want to triggering EXTI0_IRQHandler. I think you want to mention to asm("B 0x58"), It is address of EXTI0_IRQHandler.

Comment: @peymankhalili The NVIC is offset from the vector table by the exceptions. Maybe bit6 is not the IRQ you think it is. Also, you can't branch without link and expect to return. Search for the Procedure Call Standard.

Comment: from core_cm3.h we have `static __INLINE void NVIC_EnableIRQ(IRQn_Type IRQn)
{
  NVIC->ISER[((uint32_t)(IRQn) >> 5)] = (1 << ((uint32_t)(IRQn) & 0x1F)); /* enable interrupt */
}` and from stm32f10x.h we have `typedef enum IRQn{...EXTI0_IRQn                  = 6, ...}` if you do that calculation we get to `NVIC->ISER[0] |= BIT6;` for activating `EXTI0_IRQn` Interrupt, so for pending according to that files we get `NVIC->ISPR[0] |= BIT6;`. so exactly I know that I am enable pending bit of "EXTI0_IRQn", so we must get "void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)" running, where is the problem??

Comment: @peymankhalili When I test your given snippets. It works fine. You must have something else going on.